# Linear transformation of a random variable

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables

Is there a name for the class of distributions where a linear transformation does not alter the underlying distribution? In particular, adding a constant changes the mean and multiplication by a constant changes the variance (and the mean if it is non-zero).

For example, if $z \sim N  \left( 0,1 \right)    $ then $Y=az+b \sim N \left( b,a^2 \right) $, and so the linear transformation $Y$  also follows a normal distribution.

The only two examples I can think of are the Normal distribution and the continuous uniform distribution. Are there any more?

Comment: There are quite a few other named families of distributions, such as the Cauchy, and the Laplace.

Comment: Let $X$ be any random variable with mean 0 and variance 1.  We shall say that $Y \sim C_X(a,b)$ if $Y$ has the same distribution as $aX+b$. So then if $Y \sim C_X(a,b)$ then $cY+d \sim C_X(ac,bc+d)$.  Also, $Y \sim C_X(a,b) \implies E[Y]=b, Var(Y)=a^2$.

Comment: I still do not get it. If X follows any distribution ( for example log normal, normal, exponential....), the linear transfirmation Y=aX+b will belong to the same family of distributions,the only difference being a scaling and a shift of the distribution but its familly remains unchanged. Is this correct? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to check out the location-scale family of distributions.

Consider constants $\theta$ and $\tau$ where $\tau \in \mathbb{R}, ~\theta  > 0$. A family of distributions is called a location-scale family if $X$ is a random variable and $Y=\tau+\theta X$ both belong to the same family of distributions. We call $\tau$ the location parameter and $\theta$ the scale parameter.

In particular,

- a family of distributions is a *scale* family if $X$ and $Y=\theta X$ both belong to the same family of distributions.
- a family of distributions is a *location* family if $X$ and $Y=\tau+X$ both belong to the same family of distributions.